# How do I create & train a neural net to predict a stock closing price at T+5min using OHLC and other data?

Tags: neural-networks, time-series, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a neural network and train it to test predictability of short term stock price movements.

I've collated a 1-min open, high, low, closing and volume dataset for a particular stock. The idea is to train a network to crunch the data for times T - 1, T - 2, T - 3, T - 4, T - 5 to predict T + 5 closing price. Ideally, the network takes 7 input vectors

`{{open}, {high}, {low}, {close}, {volume}, {dayofweek}, {minutes_since_open}}`

over the past 5 minutes, i.e., 7 inputs x 5 time-steps, to produce a single output: `{close}` at T + 5.

I'm still a bit rough, dusting off my Mathematica skills, as the last time I used it was with V7, before all the new features :)

Would really love some help here...

Here's a link to the data set ([csv](http://skenchaizar.com/wakanda/fb_1min_1q2019_ohlcvmd.csv)) :)

Comment: Have you looked into the `Predict` function to get started?

Comment: My understanding is that Predict is more of a statistical function not a NN per se.... am I correct?

Comment: @CuriousDudeFromEgypt, `Predict` is considered supervised machine learning.  You put labeled data in and it builds a model you can use for future data.  I recommend you start there before you move into the `NetTrain` family of functions.

Comment: @CuriousDudeFromEgypt `Predict[data, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]` does use `NeuralNetwork.`

Comment: I retracted the flag because I found the person in the wolfram community dealing with the topic.

Comment: @Xminer will give this a spin... (a) do you know what type of neural net does  `Predict` use? (b) I managed to create & train a sample subset of the data using a `GatedRecurrentLayer[10] + LinearLayer` (borrowing from another post), what’s a better network chain? (c) is there any documentation/pointer that explains how many inputs does each layer type have, how many outputs? I’m still a bit confused... Thanks :)

Comment: (a) after run `Predict`,you can see NN with `List @@ % // "Model" /. # & // "Network" /. # &` (b) `optimal structure` depends on `your objective function`,the problem you're working on. **For What** (*really important*) are you trying to predict the short-term movement? (c) `How to visualize Network Structure`,you mean? Play with  [NetGraph Examples](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetGraph.html)

Comment: @Xminer ... so, I couldn't get `Predict` to work with my input vectors, not sure what I'm doing wrong (error msg below):  
`Predict::mlincfttp: Incompatible variable type (Numerical) and variable value ({30.7399}).`  
An example of the input vectors below:  
`{{{31.07, 30.95, 30.99, 30.946, 30.915}, {31.12, 31.05, 31., 30.97, 
   30.97}, {30.9, 30.905, 30.88, 30.895, 30.89}, {30.96, 30.99, 30.94,
    30.9154, 30.895}, {1216676, 600033, 462164, 357901, 248249}, {1, 
   2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5}} -> {30.7399},{..etc..}`  
Ideas?

Comment: @CuriousDudeFromEgypt Why `close-open` is  always negative in your data?

Answer (score 5):

This is for example

```
data = Import@
  "C:\\Users\\myAccount\\Downloads\\fb_1min_1q2019_ohlcvmd (2).csv";
trainset = 
 Table[data[[i]] -> data[[i, 4]], {i, 2, 
   Length@data - .3 Length@data}];
predictor=Predict[trainset, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
List @@ predictor // "Model" /. # & // "Network" /. # &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next,For Answer.

First Setting Up the Network.
I used eLU as activation layer.

```
trainet=NetGraph[
{BatchNormalizationLayer[],
LinearLayer[30],
ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid[-500#]*(1*Exp[#]-1)+LogisticSigmoid[500#]*#&],LinearLayer[1]},
    {NetPort["Input"]->1,
    1->2,
    2->3,
    3->4},"Input"->7,"Output"->1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Train it.

```
trainedNet = 
  NetTrain[trainet, <|"Input" -> Keys@trainset, 
    "Output" -> Evaluate@({#} & /@ Values@trainset)|>, 
   LossFunction -> MeanAbsoluteLossLayer[]];
```

Make ValidationSet And Check the error.

```
validationset = 
  Table[data[[i]] -> data[[i, 4]], {i, 
    IntegerPart[Length@data - .3 Length@data + 1], Length@data}];
errors = (trainedNet[Keys@#1] - Values@#1) & /@ validationset;
ListLinePlot@Flatten@errors
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

When `Predict` receives a matrix as an input, it is internally vectorized, so it seems that there is no problem in this way.
[image]

Comment: I spent some time trying to get my head around the example above...some stuff I don't understand... could you break down `List @@ % // "Model" /. # & // "Network" /. # &` to me please?
Also the training set is a {7} -> {1} set....what I'm looking for is a {5x7}->{1} set to use for training, is there a way to use `Predict` with that?

Comment: updated my code. check the structure of `List@@predictor`,then you'll notice something like `<|"Model"-> ....<|"Network"->...|>|>` I used 7-dimensional input in the answer because it took time, or as an example it was cumbersome. Try replacing the input part with `Flatten@data [[i-4;;i]]-> data[[i,4]]` and `"Input"->7` with `"Input"->35`

Comment: Hmmm...so the idea is to flatten the 5x7 input matrix into 35? Also, the 5 = T-1, T-2... T-5 vectors , each vector is o,h,l,c,vol,minuteindex,dayoftheweek. The o,h,l,c numbers are similar but vol is different, min runs from 1 to 390 and day runs from 1 to 5... wouldn’t flattening make a mess of all of that? Also does normalization also make its own mess? Is it better to normalize each vector individually before feeding the network?

Comment: please check my update.